# debug tool for Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, embedded

I am building WES 7 OS by running our C# application to see which package I need to add to. Most of the time I can get enough information from the error by viewing the System Event. Then I can add right package to the Answer file to create the OS image. But sometime I cannot find enough information from the System Event Viewer.

Is there any tool (debugger?) I can use to trace which file\library\dll is missing which cause our application crash during the runtime? I cannot install Visual Studio on that testing machine.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Walker is a fantastic tool for this: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It used to be included with the SDK, but I'm not sure if it is anymore.  In any case, I'm sure the one on the dependencywalker.com site is more up-to-date.